# Webpack and angular 1 uglify plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm getting the failed to instantiate module error when I use the uglify js plugin;
It works just fine when I don't include any plugins, how can I minify it for production?
This is my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    vendor: ['angular'],
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    watch: true
};
```

My app.js:

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
require("./css/style.css");

angular.module('todoApp', ['ui.router']).config(require('./routes'));

require('./services/todoService');

require('./controllers/mainController');
require('./controllers/homeController');
require('./controllers/aboutController');
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you didn't follow the [dependency injection guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) concerning dependency annotation.
You have a few options:

1. In `controllers/mainController`, specify `mainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];` (adapt as necessary).
2. Use the [`ng-annotate-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-annotate-loader). Depending on your code style, you might have to annotate constructors with `/*@ngInject*/`

To not miss a dependency annotation while developing, you might want to enable [strict dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection).

Comment: Seems to work now however I'm getting some errors when I run npm build but the app still works;WARNING in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Dropping unused function nodesetLinkingFn [./~/angular/angular.js:10491,0]
Dropping unused function directiveLinkingFn [./~/angular/angular.js:10498,0]
Dropping unused variable arrayMode [./~/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:854,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable ignoreUpdate [./~/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:2098,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable inherited [./~/angular-ui-